# Interface between FileMaker and R

Tags: r, filemaker

I would like to run an R Script on some of my data which is contained in a FileMaker database. Are there any options for having a live interface between R and FileMaker? I'd be interested in doing statistical analysis, data clustering algorithms and visualizations.

Answer (score 1):

How are you serving your FileMaker database? If you are using FileMaker Server, there are many options for querying the database, depending on the version of FileMaker Server. Off the top of my head: SQL over ODBC, XML, PHP API, REST Data API (version 16)

Comment: Yes this helps. We have FM on a self-hosted server. Now we have some databases in 11 and some in version 15. Which would be the highest performance and which the most intuitive to use with R? I have used the RODBC package with success but it’s a lot of work to set up. I’m looking for other options. Is there one that lets me do a full data extract daily and then an incremental refresh as needed?

Comment: Version 15 is supposedly faster than  11, but it depends more on the server hardware, ie. plenty of ram, fast disks, network etc. and database design.
All the API's I mentioned are identical in the 2 versions, but the REST Data API only exists in version 16.
If you are able to upgrade to 16, that would be the easiest option. You send your POST or GET requests and get a JSON object returned.
Otherwise, both PHP and XML are pretty straightforward if the server is enabled for it and has a web server. If you don't have web access, ODBC is pretty much what's left.

Comment: As for extracting the subset you need, you will need to send your date/time filter criteria in the request to be matched against relevant fields in the database, whatever method you choose.

Comment: Do you have any good examples? Which allow both read and write access? And which are best integrated with R?

Comment: I'm not aware of any R integration as such, but you only need to write out the calls to most of these methods using standard web requests. ODBC is more complicated, but straight forward after you get through the initial setup. All of them provide both read and write access depending of the user's credentials. For examples and implementation, I advice you to check out this documentation from FileMaker.
https://fmhelp.filemaker.com/docs/16/en/fms16_cwp_guide.pdf
https://fmhelp.filemaker.com/docs/16/en/fm16_odbc_jdbc_guide.pdf
https://fmhelp.filemaker.com/docs/16/en/restapi/